# Fast way to copy from GPU to CPU

Tags: camera, opengles

I have made some image processing shaders to reduce the CPU load.

But the slow GPU to CPU data copy is something I didn't expect. (It takes around a second to copy a single image)

As far as I know, CPU and GPU are sharing the memory. Is there a fast way to move the data?

The image is 1920x1080 RGB and mapped on a texture. I have used GetTextureData() function of raylib to copy the texture on GPU to CPU.

Comment: does [this](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=250086) help at all?